# Which is the most efficient way to migrate from a VS window c++ project to a linux one?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, visual-studio

Currently I'm transferring a c++ project into linux which was previously developed for windows with Visual Studio. I'm using Netbeans/Eclipse for the time being. So I'm wondering whether there is a more efficient way to migrate than that of creating a new c++ project and just adding the cpp and h files, since I have very little experience on VS.

Comment: That's probably the simplest way. Or you can opt to use a meta-build system which can create project files for many other build systems or IDEs (like e.g. CMake or similar systems).

Comment: Have you checked the [Visual C++ For Linux](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualCPPTeam.VisualCforLinuxDevelopment) extension? VS 2017 supports Linux development directly but it's still at the RC stage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to use [CMake](https://cmake.org/). CMake is a cross-plattform build tool which allows you to build your program for different platforms. Like this you can also choose your IDE because CMake can build project files for different IDEs.

To start with CMake you should learn the basics in [cmake.org - CMake Tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: I have used Cmake to build libraries using Vs but not to create a generic file for other IDEs to use. Is there any reference example or relevant info that I can check, because I only found example for creating cmake lists for Vs projects ?

Comment: You create a CMakelists.txt not especially for VS. If you created a CMakelist.txt you open cmake navigate to the folder where your CMakelists.txt is placed and then you press configure/generate. The Cmake asks you what type of output/build you want to generate. There you can choose between unixMakefiles/MSVC/Xcode.... .

Comment: one final question is there a way to export from an existing Vs project a Cmakelists.txt in order to use it according to your way ?

Comment: If there is a way, i don't know it. So you got to write the cmake lists on your own.